# Improving audio quality when using virtual audio cable with Skype

Tags: audio, virtual

I have installed virtual audio (VAC) cable on my computer to be able to share audio when watching youtube video with other people on skype. It seems to work but the sound from both my mic and the video starts breaking up when I turn on the video. Sound is ok without video and I can hear the video sound fine through the VAC.

I believe that the problem may be related to the setting eg bit rate but I don't know much about audio setting to figure out exactly what's wrong and how to fix it.